# Is there a text-input list in PowerApps that can be exported to a mutli-line variable?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I'm looking to create a list-field that a user can input a list of variables.

The list will then be stored in a multi-line variable in SharePoint separated by a delimiter.

An example would be an input of:

- Apples
- Bananas
- Cherries

Output: Apples;Bananas;Cherries.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally possible using a Collection and the Concat function in PowerApps.

- **Button:**

  - `OnSelect` property set to

```
Collect(colList, TextInput1.Text);
Set(varReset, true);
Set(varReset, false);
Set(varReset, true);
```

- **Textbox:**

  - `Reset` property set to `varReset`
- **Label:**

  - `Text` property set to `Concat(colList, Value, ";"`

From there, just `Patch` or `SubmitForm` the Label into a Sharepoint Column!

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! This is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I'm glad to help!